# code crashes while opencv function circles from HoughCircles is running

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I get error message R6010 - abort() has been called in my really simple code. I have in properties linker input: opencv_ts300.lib
opencv_ts300d.lib
opencv_world300.lib
opencv_world300d.lib

OpenCV Error in cmd: Assertion failed ( radius >= 0 && thickness <= MAX_THICKNESS && 0 <= shift && shift <= XY_SHIFT ) in cv::circle win64-vc12 imgproc\src\drawing.cpp line 1746.

I use Visual Studio 2012 openCV 3.0.0

Code:

```
VideoCapture cap(0);

if ( !cap.isOpened() ) { 
     cout << "Cannot open the web cam" << endl;
     return -1;
}

vector<Vec3f> circles;
int radius;
Point center;

while (true) {
    bSuccess = cap.read(imgOriginal);

     if (!bSuccess) {     
         cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
         break;
    }

    cvtColor(imgOriginal,grayImage1,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    GaussianBlur(grayImage1,grayImage1,Size(9,9),2,2);

    /// Apply the Hough Transform to find the circles
    HoughCircles( grayImage1, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,20,100,155,20,300 );

    /// Draw the circles detected
    for( size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++ ) {
        //center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
        center.x = cvRound(circles[i][0]);
        center.y = cvRound(circles[i][1]);

        radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
        // circle center
        circle( imgOriginal, center, 3, Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0 );
        // circle outline
        circle( imgOriginal, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
    }    

    imshow("Hough circles",imgOriginal);

namedWindow("Control", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "Control"
}

return 0;
```

Please can somebody help me with that? Maybe something with opencv? Or I think my laptop can causes it...

Comment: So as it says: `radius` should be >= 0 && `thickness` should be <= MAX_THICKNESS && `shift` should be >= 0 && `shift` should <= XY_SHIFT. Check those variables in your code. In which line you are getting the error?

Comment: Error is in line circle( imgOriginal, center, radius, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 8, 0 );
Yes, radius is minus value but i dont know why.
It is piece of code from opencv website and it should work

Comment: So in your case: `radius` is radius `thickness` is 3, `shift` is 0. Did you debug your code to see the actual values of ALL the variables, statement by statement? Using F-10 in Visual Studio

Comment: "Visual Studio 12 stop working" -- it seems to be working exactly as designed. It's you code that crashes and burns after you call an OpenCV function with invalid parameters and fail to handle the exception thrown when it validates its inputs.

Comment: Yes, in debugging it loops 3 times and in 4 loop it crashes because radius = -2147483648

Dan, your comment really helped me, thank you very much, I hope that you know sarcasm

Comment: Good that you solved your problem..

Comment: I knew this before, but i dont know why there is that number, any advice how to fix it?

Comment: That's why your system is crashing. Radius is < 0. Your question has been answered. Now please edit your question to reflect and state that. For now I am looking at your code to see why this is happening

Comment: you are mixing debug and release libraries. use only the ones that fit to your build.

Comment: ooouu, it is working ! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be with:

```
HoughCircles( grayImage1, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,20,100,155,20,300 );
```

The problem here is that your statement doesn't say what the last variables are or also what is `circles`.

Here's how I would do it:

```
circles = cv.HoughCircles( grayImage1, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 2,20,#find Circles
param1=100,param2=155,mixRadius20,maxRadius=300 );

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:#draw circles
    # draw the outer circle
    cv.circle(grayImage1,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)
    # draw the center of the circle
    cv.circle(grayImage1,(i[0],i[1]),2,(0,0,255),3)
```

I recommend checking the [API REFERANCE](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d53/tutorial_py_houghcircles.html) for this.

Hope this helps!